# How to do this in DDD without referencing the Repository from the domain entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm struggling hard to find a proper design to avoid referencing a Repository from an Entity... Let's say I've got the classic `Customer` and `Order` classes like so:

```
public class Customer {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order {
    ...
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }

    public void Submit() {
       ...
    }
}

public class OrderItem {
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say that the Product's selling price depends for some reason on the fact that the Product was also purchased (or not) on the previous Order, the number of items on the current order and previous order, etc. I could do this:

```
public void Submit() {
    Order lastOrder = this.Customer.Orders.LastOrDefault();
    CalculatePrice(lastOrder);
```

but that would **load the whole order list of Orders** when I only really need the last one!

What I'd like to do is something more like this:

```
public void Submit() {
    Order lastOrder = _orderRepository.GetLastOrderFor(Customer);
    CalculatePrice(lastOrder);
```

But I understand referencing the `OrderRepository` in the Domain is bad DDD. So, what do I do? Do I have to put the Submit() elsewhere than in the Domain? If so, where do you suggest?

Comment: if that is a stable business rule that happens for all purchases, you could change your command as such to Submit(Order mostRecent).
Or you could also externalize the pricing algorithm to another class and pass that into the command Submit(IPriceCalculator calc)

Comment: If I externalize the pricing algorithm, where the IPriceCalculator implementation be? That really seems like to Domain Logic to me, no?

Comment: It is simply a domain service, so it belongs in your domain package.

Comment: And that IPriceCalculator implementation would have a reference to an IOrderRepository... but, shouldn't I just do a OrderSubmitter Domain Service instead?

Comment: submitting an order sounds like a behavior belonging to an order, but only you know your context.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. So I think it's right to say the referencing an Repository in a domain _Entity_ is bad design, but it's OK to reference it in a Domain _Service_ ..

Comment: correct. domain services are needed when a particular behavior/process does not "fit" within an existing class. you could shoe horn it in, but you'll also notice the increase/decrease in cohesion and coupling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two varieties:

Create a domain service and add a dependency to the repository from it:

```
public class MyPricingStrategy : IPricingStrategy
{
  public MyPricingStrategy(IOrderRepository repository)
  { ... }
}
```

this way you will make domain service reference repository which is not very bad idea.

Another option is to make the pricing strategy a domain object with application layer passing it required data from repository:

```
public class LastOrderPricingStrategy
{
  public LastOrderPricingStrategy(Order lastOrder)
  { ... }
}
```

in application layer

```
var lastOrder = orderRepository.GetLastOrder(currentCustomer);
var pricingStrategy = new LastOrderPricingStrategy(lastOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Customer object could have a LastOrder property:

```
public class Customer {
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public Order LastOrder { get; set; }
}
```

So part of the logic of making an order sets this field, and this will be saved with the Customer. Then when you load the customer, you will quickly know what the last order way, and make your decisions based on that accordingly.

Another way, if you are using an ORM like NHibernate, you could create a multi query to eagerly load the Orders collection with only the last order. then you could go back to using this:

```
public void Submit() {
    Order lastOrder = this.Customer.Orders.LastOrDefault();
    CalculatePrice(lastOrder);
```

and it would not need to load anything because the order you need will be in there. Eagerly loading only the objects I'm going to need in a collection is a pattern I use quite a lot.

Comment: Yes, I am using NHibernate. Are you saying that I get Eager load _only_ the last order and then Lazy load all orders if I access anything but the last order? How would I do that?! I thought eager loading was to load all child objects when loading the parent...

Comment: This puzzled me at first because it has never come up, and I was wondering why it never had. I've never eagerly loaded one object, and then needed the rest. But then it was obvious: If ever I've needed all the objects, I've eagerly loaded them all! You wouldn't only load one object if you're going to need them al.

Comment: The problem with your suggested approach is that if the Customer has 5000 orders, we load them all even thought we only actually use the last one (in this  price calculation scenario). This is an unnecessary performance hit...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that at all. What I'm saying is, if you are only going to use one order, only load that one order. If you are going to use all the orders, load all the orders.